# Jquery PHP calling a div id and value from a script execution

Tags: jquery

I guess my trouble is that I’m new to Jquery. My question: is  this even possible? I had a button that worked when I pressed it to delete something/anything. It simply used a div id and an Input value to identify it and perform the action(I used php/html). I now would like  to use drag and drop to delete the exact same thing only without using/pressing a button. Now using drag and drop to activate the button action. I used this script (with the jquery library) and some simple html/php.

```
<div id="image_manager">
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="delete_picture_form" >
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete_image"/>
<input type="submit" value="DELETE IMAGE" />
</form>
</div>

//when I drag image below, I want it to act as if I pressed the working button above
<img src="../../images/<?php echo    $product['productCode']; ?>_s.png">

<div  class="trash" >
<img src="trashh.png" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#image_manager> form').draggable({
revert: 'invalid'
});
$('.trash').droppable({
activeClass: 'highlight',
hoverClass: 'highlight-accept',
drop: function(event, ui) {
puffRemove($(ui.draggable));
}
});
});
function puffRemove(which) {
var $this = $(which),
image_width = 128,
scale_factor = $this.outerWidth() / image_width,
frame_count = 5,
$trash, $puff;
// create container
$trash = $('<div class="puff"></div>')
.css({
height: $this.outerHeight(),
left: $this.offset().left,
top: $this.offset().top,
width: $this.outerWidth(),
position: 'absolute',
overflow: 'hidden'
})
.appendTo('body');
// add the animation image
$puff = $('<img class="puff" src="epuff.png"/>')
.css({
width: image_width * scale_factor,
height: (frame_count * image_width) * scale_factor
})
.data('count', frame_count)
.appendTo($trash);
// remove the original element
$this.animate({
opacity: 0    }, 'fast').remove();
// or even
// $this.fadeOut('fast');
(function animate() {
var count = $puff.data('count');
if(count) {
var top = frame_count - count;
var height = $puff.height() / frame_count;
$puff.css({
"top": - (top * height),
'position': 'absolute'
});
$trash.css({
'height': height
})
$puff.data("count", count - 1);
setTimeout(animate, 75);
}
else {    $puff.parent().remove();

//I added the below to fetch the form's div id and value which was used by the button
```

document.getElementById("image_manager").value=document.getElementById("delete_picture_form    ").value.appendTo($puff)
}})();}

Comment: You have a number of issues, most importantly, it doesn't look like you're including the `jQuery.js` library anywhere. Also, when you're using `jQuery` you are able to do `$("#myDiv")` instead of `document.getElementById('myDiv')`. And lastly, have a look at the [jQuery docs for `.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) which I think you're trying to with that `.value` bit. (which, in jQuery is `.val()`. tl;dr : [http://api.jquery.com/](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: Also, this is your friend : [http://jsbeautifier.org/](http://jsbeautifier.org/) works for html and css, too.